# Bipyridyl complex isomers

Tags: coordination-compounds, stereochemistry

What type of stereoisomers do these two complex compounds represent?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

These are examples of enantiomerism or optical isomerism. If you imagine a mirror placed between the two images you will see that they are mirror images of each other. If you try to rotate them to match up (easiest to do with a model, either physical or virtual) you will find that they are non-superimposable and this is what gives them their isomeric properties. The two isomers rotate plane polarised light in opposite directions (this is where the name, optical isomerism, comes from).

The $\Delta$ and $\Lambda$ labels distinguish the two isomers by their absolute stereochemical configuration.

An decent explanation of this type of isomerism can be found [here](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Inorganic_Chemistry/Coordination_Chemistry/Isomers/Stereoisomers/Optical_Isomers_in_Inorganic_Complexes).

Comment: But what type? Central, axial, planar or helicity chirality?

Comment: @Marko As you mention, there are multiple types. In this case, it's stereoisomers around a central point (the metal center).

Comment: @Marko This is an example o helical chirality.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_chirality